# xslt call template with unique select id

Tags: xslt

i have the following template which i'm using to dynamically populate rows so they each have this a select dropdown:

```
<xsl:template name="MessageTimesOptionsFrom">
 <xsl:param name="selected" />
  <select id="StartTime" name="StartTime">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($MessageTimesFrom)/option" mode="o">
    <xsl:with-param name="selected" select="$selected" />
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </select>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="MessageTimesFrom">
  <option value="">From</option>
  <option value="00:00">12:00am</option>
  <option value="00:10">12:10am</option>
  <option value="00:20">12:20am</option>
  <option value="00:30">12:30am</option>
  <option value="00:40">12:40am</option>
  <option value="00:50">12:50am</option>
  <option value="01:00">1:00am</option>
</xsl:variable>
```

and the html looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown_container">
 <xsl:call-template name="MessageTimesOptionsFrom">
  <xsl:with-param name="selected">
   <xsl:value-of select="$starttime" />
  </xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
</div>
```

To process the form, i'm going to need each "select" to have a unique id.  Is there a way to do this when calling the template either in the xsl or html?  Right now each row of dropdowns obviously have the same id - "StartTime"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually XSLT maps some input node on which you can call `generate-id()` to an HTML output element so assuming you have e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
<div class="dropdown_container">
 <xsl:call-template name="MessageTimesOptionsFrom">
  <xsl:with-param name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="selected" select="$starttime" />
 </xsl:call-template>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

then you can use

```
<xsl:template name="MessageTimesOptionsFrom">
 <xsl:param name="id"/>
 <xsl:param name="selected" />
  <select id="StartTime{$id}" name="StartTime">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($MessageTimesFrom)/option" mode="o">
    <xsl:with-param name="selected" select="$selected" />
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </select>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course depending on your needs you could simply use `<select id="{$id}" ...>`.